# Natural sort order in Midnight Commander

Tags: mc

How can I fix sort order in Midnight Commander to sort numbers correctly?

[image]

I need such order:

```
1.png
9.png
10.png
19.png
22.png
a.png
test.png
z.png
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Posting an answer as requested.  MC has sorting by version, which is their name for natural sort.  You can enable it by <kbd>F9</kbd> -> `Sort order` -> `Version`.